# javascript replaces text on loop from separate strings

Tags: javascript, loops, split, str-replace

I made loop for, from split string and try to find some text and replace it by the result of separate string, here for example :

```js
function replaceStr(str, find, replace) {
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(find[i], 'gi'), replace[i]);
  }
  return str;
}

var str = 'some text contain car and some house contain car, or car contain someone';
var values = "cat,dog,chicken";

splt = values.split(',');

for (i = 0; i < splt.length; i++) {
  var find = ['car'];
  var replace = ['' + values[i] + ''];
  replaced = replaceStr(str, find, replace);
}
console.log(replaced);
//console.log(splt.length);
```

but the result return zeros

I want find all "car" text and replace it from splited text by comma characters
anyone can help me please..

Comment: `['' + values[i] + ''];` - Why the `''`? And why `values[i]`? `values` is a string. Should be `splt[i]`

Comment: Please add desired outcome. Do you want to replace each `car` with all the words in `values`? Or one at the time?

Comment: Well! above of what @Abdreas has said there is also error in your Values Array, there is no Car text in your array

Comment: The whole thing doesn’t appear to make much sense. Why are you looping in _two_ places here? Why are you passing arrays to your `replaceStr` function, that only ever contain one single element? And if you only want to replace one single occurrence of the search term at a time (I’m assuming you do), then why does your regex contain the `g` modifier?

Comment: @CBroe i copied that function replace from this site :D.. it's always work for every string ^^ i even don't understand what I'm doing,, maybe I better explain in words instead of sample code ^^

Answer (score 2):

hum what is the goal of your replaceStr function ?
maybe this is enough :

```js
var str = 'some text contain car and some house contain car, or car contain someone';
var values = "cat,dog,chicken";

splt = values.split(',');

for (i = 0; i < splt.length; i++) {
   var find = 'car';
   str = str.replace(find, splt[i]);
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess implicitly from your question you want to replace "car" with cat, dog, chicken progressively to achieve this:
"some text contain cat and some house contain dog, or chicken contain someone"

So roughly this would be your solution:

```
var str = 'some text contain car and some house contain car, or car contain someone';
var values = "cat,dog,chicken";
var splt = values.split(',');
var replaced = str;
for (i = 0; i < splt.length; i++) {
  replaced = replaced.replace('car', splt[i]);  
}
console.log(replaced);
```